How to fully refresh PM2 environment variables without "kill" command?
My old ecosystem.config.js file had these env variables
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'test_app',
      script: './bin/www',
      env: {
        GENERIC_VALUE: 'old value',
        FIRST_TEST_VALUE: 'first value',
      },
    },
  ],
};

My replacement file has some changes to the env object
      env: {
        GENERIC_VALUE: 'new value',
        SECOND_TEST_VALUE: 'second value',
      },

In an attempt to implement these changes I run
$ pm2 restart ecosystem.config.js

To confirm these changes happened I run
$ pm2 env 0

This shows the generic value has changed, and the second key-value pair is now available, but the first key-value pair remains available.  I don't want this.
How do I get the first key-value pair to no longer be available?  In other words, how to I get PM2 to simply refresh all env variables based upon what's in the current ecosystem.config file?
I've tried these commands...
$ pm2 restart all --update-env
$ pm2 reload all

..but that first key-value pair still comes up.
The only thing that seems to work (per this answer) is to kill/start the process.
$ pm2 kill
$ pm2 start ecosystem.config.js

But this seems heavy handed.  Is there any other way?
